# Jenkins and Powershell: Start-Process with "-Wait" parameter

Tags: powershell, jenkins

As part of a freestyle Jenkins job (Not a scripted pipeline) I'm attempting to run a Powershell step that executes a script as another user. I believe the Powershell step is provided by the Jenkins Powershell plugin.

To do this I'm using the Start-Process cmdlet and specifying the credential object as a parameter. The credential is pulled from the Jenkins credential store.

Everything works fine other than the Start-Process command doesn't seem to respect the "-Wait" flag that I'm providing. The idea here is that the the script I execute as another user produces some files based on the stdout/stderr and I need to wait for these to be created before I can continue with the job.

I'm doing something like this:

```
$runTestArgs = "-file $env:WORKSPACE\Scripts\runtest.ps1", `
"-Server", ` 
"-TestCategory $($env:TestCategory)"

Start-Process -FilePath powershell.exe -ArgumentList $runTestArgs -Credential $cred -RedirectStandardOutput "stdout.txt" -RedirectStandardError "stderr.txt" -Wait
```

However the job continues executing and doesn't wait for the spawned process to complete. I need to later  grab the stdout.txt and stderr.txt for parsing.

I've tested these exact steps on the Jenkins slave, running everything as the user that Jenkins runs under and it appears to work perfectly. It waits for the Start-Process to complete before carrying on and grabbing the content of those files. The behaviour doesn't seem to be the same when I try it through the actual Jenkins web interface by running a "build" on the job.

I also tried something similar that I found here that involves creating an object from the process like:

```
$ps = Start-Process -FilePath powershell.exe -ArgumentList $runTestArgs -Credential $cred -RedirectStandardOutput "stdout.txt" -RedirectStandardError "stderr.txt" -Wait -PassThru

$ps.WaitForExit()
```

Which again, works OK on the slave when I run it as the Jenkins service user but doesn't seem to work when I build the actual job.

Wasn't sure if this disparity between me running it as that user manually and Jenkins executing it was because it seems to wrap PowerShell steps, executing like this (Snippet from the console):

`powershell.exe -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File C:\Users\JENKIN~1\AppData\Local\Temp\jenkins3475017597789662720.ps1`

Any ideas?

Thanks